# How to show timestamp with time zone for mobile clients

Tags: spring, postgresql, rest, spring-mvc, ionic-framework

I have a DB and an application server located in NYC. I want to write a mobile application, which will be used by users from different cities (Los Angeles, New York, Miami). I use `Postgresql` as database, `Spring MVC` for backend and `Ionic` for mobile application. My question is - when user A from Los Angeles inserts a data into database for time `10:00 AM`, how should I show this data to the user from New York, because there is a timezone difference? How should I store this kind of data in `Postgres`, and how should I process it in `Spring MVC`? Should my rest return time in milliseconds, or should I use `timestamp` or `timestampz`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the data as TIMESTAMPTZ.  This is what that data type is for. [This blog post](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html) explains it a bit.

TIMESTAMPTZ stores all timestamps in absolute time, and displays them based on the user's timezone settings.  For example:

```
postgres=# create table times ( some_time timestamptz );
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# set timezone = 'US/Eastern';
SET
postgres=# insert into times values ( '2017-09-15 10:00:00' );
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# set timezone = 'US/Pacific';
SET
postgres=# select * from times;
       some_time        
------------------------
 2017-09-15 07:00:00-07
(1 row)

postgres=# set timezone = 'US/Eastern';
SET
postgres=# select * from times;
       some_time        
------------------------
 2017-09-15 10:00:00-04
(1 row)
```

This allows you to display the correct time, from the user's perspective, even for a user who themselves moves around and changes time zones.  You just need to remember to set the time zone in JDBC when you connect.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot